# Open Graph meta tags to share a GIF on facebook

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I've put meta tags for Title and url. Url for gif is working fine but is not showing the title in preview on Facebook. Is there anything extra configuration for this?

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: For me, gifs are displaying as static images. Did you manage to get them animated?

Answer (score 2):

this seems to be a facebook bug.
the best workaround is to post both

og:url  and og:image pointing to the gif

the second time this is posted to facebook, it will work!

more discussion here: [How does Giphy share gifs to facebook? (2015, NOT FLASH ANYMORE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216481/how-does-giphy-share-gifs-to-facebook-2015-not-flash-anymore)