# How does Giphy share gifs to facebook? (2015, NOT FLASH ANYMORE)

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, gif

If I paste the following URL into Facebook I can share an animated gif. It's not a movie and not flash, Facebook [now supports gifs](http://www.forbes.com/sites/amitchowdhry/2015/06/01/facebook-starts-supporting-animated-gifs/) without those workarounds. I can click it to pause and it shows "GIF" in a circle while paused.

http://giphy.com/gifs/hot-funny-cartoon-fBEDuhnVCiP16

No matter what I replicate from that page's meta tags I cannot get Facebook to share an animated gif form my own page. I've even gone so far as to copy the entire code of that page and serve it myself (Changing `<link rel="canonical"` and `<meta property="og:url"` to match my url).

[Open Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) gives identical results for both the real Giphy page and my replica. Interestingly, the preview in Object Debugger is the old style Flash movie for both pages. However, when I paste the Giphy url into my Facebook it shows the gif - my relica shows the Flash.

Do Giphy get some special treatment from Facebook? Do I need to do something different?

Answer (score 27):

I was able to create an .html file which, when the link is pasted as a status, displays as an animating (and looping) GIF in the Facebook feed. In my html page, I use the following meta tags in the header:

```
<meta property="og:site_name"   content="Site Name">
<meta property="og:url"         content="url to GIF on web">
<meta property="og:title"       content="Title of GIF page">
<meta property="og:description" content="Some description">
<meta property="og:type"        content="video.other">
<meta property="og:image"       content="Same as og:url above">
<meta property="og:image:width"  content="800">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="400">
```

The thing that gave me trouble when I was working on this was the `og:url` property. It should point directly to the GIF, not the .html file that these meta tags are a part of. Also, `og:image` should be the same as `og:url`.

I didn't test if the width and height properties are required.

Comment: This is should be the accepted answer.  The og:image and og:url being the same is critical here.

Comment: If someone then clicks on that link, are they taken directly the the gif or to the containing page?

Comment: @vegashacker Could you please post a fully working link to a working html file?

Comment: @DmytroKarataiev Here's a working html file: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vegashacker/371e00b53b3e82ea5b0920820c4bdd55/raw/a782535972f2323e2bbfcbad02e9c2dc9d496406/animated-gif-on-fb.html    Note also: the height/width is wrong in that it doesn't correspond to the size of the GIF, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @PatrickGunderson If someone clicks the animated GIF link from FB feed, they are taken to the containing page, not the animated GIF itself.

Comment: this works, the GIF is indeed displayed as a GIF in the feed. However, Facebook tries to get all the other meta tags from the GIF URL (in my case an S3 URL). As a result, fb:app_id and other tags are ignored, and I cannot track user interactions in my app analytics. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: also, is the description and title displayed on the post?

Comment: In 2020, clicking on the image pauses/resumes the animation. There is no description, only the domain name is displayed below the image. Clicking on the domain name brings you to the original page.

Answer (score 6):

Product Manager for the Giphy API team here.  No special treatment; I wish--filing bugs with Facebook takes forever.

The Flash tag is legacy and we should clean it up.  FB now does support GIFs and the answer by vegashacker is essentially correct.

Answer (score 4):

An important point which answers have missed, how to make GIF image (if clicked) redirects to the article which belongs to instead of the GIF link itself?

The important parts are:

```
<meta property="og:image"  content="url/to/image.gif">
<meta property="og:url"    content="url/to/image.gif">
<meta property="og:url"    content="url/to/article">
```

Add two `og:url` tags. First one should be the same as `og:image` pointing to the GIF image URL. Second one should be the URL to the article.

Comment: In 2020, clicking on the image pauses/resumes the animation. Adding a second `og:url` doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I looked at their source code, and I am 99% sure that they are actually showing a video. For [this gif](https://giphy.com/gifs/star-wars-80s-the-muppet-show-H2ANZTOXVepbO), there are a number of open graph meta tags associated with the page:

```html
 <meta property="og:type" content="video">
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://media.giphy.com/media/H2ANZTOXVepbO/giphy-facebook_s.jpg">
 <meta property="og:image:width" content="480">
 <meta property="og:image:height" content="270">
 <meta property="og:video" content="http://giphygifs.s3.amazonaws.com/swiphy20141103.swf?api_hostname=&amp;gif_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.giphy.com%2Fmedia%2FH2ANZTOXVepbO%2Fgiphy.gif&amp;giphy_height=297&amp;video_url=http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.giphy.com%2Fmedia%2FH2ANZTOXVepbO%2Fgiphy.mp4&amp;giphyWidth=400&amp;path=%2Fgifs%2Fstar-wars-80s-the-muppet-show-H2ANZTOXVepbO&amp;destination_url=http%3A%2F%2Fgiphy.com%2Fgifs%2FH2ANZTOXVepbO&amp;giphyHeight=297&amp;gif_id=H2ANZTOXVepbO&amp;mode=embed&amp;giphy_width=400">
 <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://giphygifs.s3.amazonaws.com/swiphy20141103.swf?api_hostname=&amp;gif_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.giphy.com%2Fmedia%2FH2ANZTOXVepbO%2Fgiphy.gif&amp;giphy_height=297&amp;video_url=http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.giphy.com%2Fmedia%2FH2ANZTOXVepbO%2Fgiphy.mp4&amp;giphyWidth=400&amp;path=%2Fgifs%2Fstar-wars-80s-the-muppet-show-H2ANZTOXVepbO&amp;destination_url=http%3A%2F%2Fgiphy.com%2Fgifs%2FH2ANZTOXVepbO&amp;giphyHeight=297&amp;gif_id=H2ANZTOXVepbO&amp;mode=embed&amp;giphy_width=400">
 <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
 <meta property="og:video:width" content="470">
 <meta property="og:video:height" content="297">
```

and most of them are video tags. These tags are associated with the page and not a gif. If you share the straight gif image, then it will not animate.

To confirm this, if you plug the page into the [Facebook URL debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), then this can be confirmed. There is no mystery, [this is shared as a flash video](http://cl.ly/image/3S3X1c3g0C08).

Comment: Definitely a gif. I just posted it to my facebook page and inspected the result in chrome dev tools. `<img class="_9_m img" src="https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCBcGH6WvU_FUPB&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.giphy.com%2Fmedia%2FH2ANZTOXVepbO%2Fgiphy.gif&amp;ext=gif" width="470" height="349" data-reactid=".18.0">`

Comment: Well, yes and no (about it being a gif). They are doing some strangeness with loading the gif via a Flash movie. Check out this url: http://giphygifs.s3.amazonaws.com/swiphy20141103.swf?api_hostname=&gif_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.giphy.com%2Fmedia%2FH2ANZTOXVepbO%2Fgiphy.gif&giphy_height=297&video_url=http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.giphy.com%2Fmedia%2FH2ANZTOXVepbO%2Fgiphy.mp4&giphyWidth=400&path=%2Fgifs%2Fstar-wars-80s-the-muppet-show-H2ANZTOXVepbO&destination_url=http%3A%2F%2Fgiphy.com%2Fgifs%2FH2ANZTOXVepbO&giphyHeight=297&gif_id=H2ANZTOXVepbO&mode=embed&giphy_width=400

Comment: That's the url that they reference from their `og:video` tag. I think they are doing some flash programming. I believe that this is the trick that they are using: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/load-external-swf-swf.html

Comment: I know that's what it *looks* like *would* happen from the meta tags. But when you post it to facebook, **it is a gif**. It's an `img` tag with `src="...safe_image.php..."` and that url returns a gif with `content-type:image/gif`

Comment: No, they're not posting 'gifs' as gif tags. They're posting them as videos. The man from Giphy said so http://www.adweek.com/socialtimes/giphy-animated-gif-files/427540

Comment: Also, if you have a look at the content, the tags are video tags

Comment: They were definitely `img` tags with `src` pointing to a gif image when I posted this question and comments. Perhaps they've changed that now.

Comment: Yep, the same test that revealed the `img` html tag with gif `src` now shows a `video` html tag.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on this for a while with Facebook debugger and found how to post swf but just today I also successfully posted my animated gif.

I simply pasted my link https://www.example.com/my.gif into Facebook debugger and it said could not find URL but displayed fine giving app id number and then I went ahead and posted in my timeline for all to see :) So no html or tags to achieve that but simply a secure link to my gif file on my server.

Never did I work out how to achieve it via html embedded!