# Open Graph Gifs that animates when shared

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to construct the `og` metatags of a website such that when the website link is shared to facebook, the preview image (a gif), animates automatically?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216481/how-does-giphy-share-gifs-to-facebook-2015-not-flash-anymore) & [here](http://www.adweek.com/socialtimes/giphy-animated-gif-files/427540) it's talked about how Giphy accomplishes it, by essentially wrapping the gif in an swf file. But it's 2016 so is there a better (and supported) way to accomplish this? I couldn't find anything in the facebook docs and I'd like to keep my `og:type` meta tag as having a value of `website`.

Here's a snippet of my metatag config obejct (I use [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) to populate the tags):

```
  { property: 'fb:app_id', content: 'some_app_id' },
  { property: 'og:description', content: 'My site's description' },
  { property: 'og:image', content: 'http://example.com' },
  { property: 'og:image:type', content: 'image/gif' },
  { property: 'og:title', content: 'My Site' },
  { property: 'og:url', content: 'http://example.com' },
  { property: 'og:type', content: 'website' },
  { property: 'og:image:width', content: '657' },
  { property: 'og:image:height', content: '411' },

  { charset: 'utf-8' },
  { property: 'og:site_name', content: 'My Site' },
  { property: 'og:locale', content: 'en_US' },
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this last summer.  My understanding was you must wrap your image in a SWF file or a javascript video player (which is really just a javascript program as far as I could tell).  Many of the big players (check out any youtube page) will have a number of ways they present their content using OG - including SWF, javascript player, just as an image, etc so that as the device they are being viewed on might not have the ability to use one or more of the methods, it can fall back on another method - i.e. degrade gracefully.

Here is a youtube header (a bit overkill?):

```
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="YouTube">
      <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKOpnK5fC4k">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Pearl Jam 10-16-2014 Detroit Mi Full Show Multicam SBD Blu-Ray">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UKOpnK5fC4k/maxresdefault.jpg">

      <meta property="og:description" content="Pearl Jam 10-16-2014 Detroit Michigan Full Show Multicam SBD Blu Ray 2014 Lightning Bolt Tour Full Show Blu Ray Torrent (Added 06-05-2015) Option 1 - http://...">

    <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="544007664">
    <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="YouTube">
      <meta property="al:ios:url" content="vnd.youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKOpnK5fC4k&amp;feature=applinks">

      <meta property="al:android:url" content="vnd.youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKOpnK5fC4k&amp;feature=applinks">
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="YouTube">
    <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.google.android.youtube">
    <meta property="al:web:url" content="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKOpnK5fC4k&amp;feature=applinks">

    <meta property="og:type" content="video">
        <meta property="og:video:url" content="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UKOpnK5fC4k">
        <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UKOpnK5fC4k">
        <meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html">
        <meta property="og:video:width" content="1280">
        <meta property="og:video:height" content="720">
        <meta property="og:video:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/UKOpnK5fC4k?version=3&amp;autohide=1">
        <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.youtube.com/v/UKOpnK5fC4k?version=3&amp;autohide=1">
        <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <meta property="og:video:width" content="1280">
        <meta property="og:video:height" content="720">

        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Pearl Jam (Musical Group)">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Pearl Jam">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="PJ">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Full Show">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Full Concert">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="HD">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Blu Ray">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Live">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Eddie Vedder (Musical Artist)">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Black">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Alive">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Even Flow">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Sirens">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Complete Concert">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Frozen Let It Go">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Pearl Jam Concert">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Pearl Jam Full Show">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Pearl Jam Full Concert">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Pearl Jam 2014">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Pearl Jam 10-16-2014">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Pearl Jam 16-10-2014">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="10-16-2014">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="16-10-2014">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Pearl Jam Detroit Full Show">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Pearl Jam Detroit 2014">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="10-16-2014 Detoit">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Pearl Jam Joe Louis Arena">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Pearl Jam Michigan">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="PJ Detroit">
        <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Joe Louis Arena">
```

Comment: Hmmm yeah giphy does something similar, using a `og:video` property in conjunction with the swf. Would you happen to know how the degrading works? Does it start with what's listed first then degrade down the list?

Comment: From my reading (I have not tested it), it tries to do the first thing first.  Here is a helptile.com:  [link](http://helptile.com/fs/881).